# Updating nested map with multiple keys

Tags: elixir

Say we have map like this:

```
state = %{
      data: %{
        "default" => %{
          "someKeyword" => %{updated: 2}},

          "baila" => %{
            "someKeyword" => %{updated: 2}},
            "morena" => %{updated: 2}
        }
      }
```

In this example there are just 2 "parent keys" to check -> `default` and `baila` in real application there would be 100s+

Now, when I get event with updated keyword `someKeyword`, how do I check all parent keys and conditionally update if key was found and some value of new key is higher then value of old key.

Something like:

```
newKeyword = %{"someKeyword" => %{updated: 3, otherdata: 4}}
newKeywordkey = List.first(Map.keys(newKeyword))

keys = Map.keys(state.data)

Enum.each(keys, fn(x) ->
  new_state = case Kernel.get_and_update_in(x, [newKeywordkey], fn(y) ->
    if y.updated < newKeyword[newKeywordkey] do
         ....
     end
    {y, newKeyword}
  end)
   do
    {l, b} -> b
  end
end)
```

Above example is terrible and doesn't work because it seemed such a messy solution that I gave up after embarrassingly long time :)

Is there simpler way to loop/check nested map like one above and conditionally update on match ?

End result should be:

```
newKeyword = %{"someKeyword" => %{updated: 3, otherdata: 4}}
....
state = %{
      data: %{
        "default" => %{
          "someKeyword" => %{updated: 3, otherdata: 4}},

          "baila" => %{
            "someKeyword" => %{updated: 3, otherdata: 4}},
            "morena" => %{updated: 2}
        }
      }
```

Comment: If the value associated with `someKeyword` is the same one for all sub-maps, wouldn't it make sense to store it on a different level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) and [`Kernel.put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3):

```
state = %{
  data: %{
    "default" => %{
      "someKeyword" => %{updated: 2}
     },
     "baila" => %{
       "morena" => %{updated: 2}
     }
  }
}

new_keyword = %{"someKeyword" => %{updated: 3, otherdata: 4}}
[{new_key, new_value}] = Map.to_list(new_keyword)

new_state = Enum.reduce(Map.keys(state.data), state, fn key, state ->
  old_value = state.data[key][new_key]
  if old_value == nil || old_value && new_value.updated > old_value.updated do
    put_in(state, [:data, key, new_key], new_value)
  else
    state
  end
end)

IO.inspect new_state
```

Output:

```
%{data: %{"baila" => %{"morena" => %{updated: 2},
      "someKeyword" => %{otherdata: 4, updated: 3}},
    "default" => %{"someKeyword" => %{otherdata: 4, updated: 3}}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a great and much easier way, see [here](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/02/01/elixir-best-practices-deeply-nested-maps).

[**Kernel.put_in/3**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3)

```
my_map = %{
  foo: %{
    bar: %{
      baz: "my value"
    }
  }
}

put_in(my_map, [:foo, :bar, :baz], "new value")
```

Comment: I use this one all the time as its so clear and concise :)

Answer (score 2):

While the answer by @Dogbert is definitely correct (with a limit it works for one key-value pair, though,) there is easier way to achieve a goal

```
new_data = %{"someKeyword" => %{updated: 3, otherdata: 4}}
%{data: state.data 
  |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> 
       {k, 
        (if v["someKeyword"] == nil ||
            v["someKeyword"][:updated] == nil ||
            v["someKeyword"][:updated] < new_data[:updated],
         do: v |> Map.merge(new_keyword), else: v)
       }
     end)
  |> Enum.into(%{})}

#⇒ %{data: %{"baila" => %{"morena" => %{updated: 2},
#       "someKeyword" => %{otherdata: 4, updated: 3}},
#     "default" => %{"someKeyword" => %{otherdata: 4, updated: 3}}}}
```

The above works for merging any new data map.

Thanks @Dogbert for pointing out that the explicit condition for `updated` is required here.

Comment: I don't think this handles "update if key was found and some value of new key is higher then value of old key", but if you use `Map.merge/3` with a simple `if`, I think it would function the same as my code and would definitely be much cleaner.